# Slither Tool Error On Contract That Inherit From Openzeppeling

Tags: solidity, security, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I'm trying to use SLITHER (the analysis tool), but when I try to use it on a contract that inherits from Open Zeppelin, it gives me this error:

```
Error: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Pausable.sol" not found: File not found."
Error: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File not found.
```

This is my contract:

```
contract WeakToken is ERC20Pausable, Ownable{
   /* etc. */
}
```

Have you successfully used the SLITHER tool with a contract that inherits from Open Zeppelin?

Answer (score 13):

Slither use [crytic-compile](https://github.com/crytic/crytic-compile) for compiling your contracts. If you specify the path to your contract `crytic-compile` will try to compile it using your installed `solc` version. `solc` can't resolve your `"@openzeppelin"` imports. I am going to guess you are using some tooling like **Hardhat** or **Truffle**, if you are I would recommend using `slither .` instead of specifying the path to the contract; in this way, crytic can realize you are using a framework like **Hardhat** and compile with it.

Another solution could be using the `--solc-remaps` from `crytici-compile`, your command would be something like:

```
slither <path_to_your_contract> --solc-remaps @openzeppelin=node_modules/@openzeppelin
```

Answering your last questions: Yes, I have used slither with contracts that inherit from openzeppelin contracts. IMO The easiest way would be using **Hardhat** or **Truffle**.

Comment: Thanks A lot For Your Reply Dear ! 
I resolve use this :
slither contracts/WeakToken.sol --solc-remaps @openzeppelin/=$(pwd)/node_modules/@openzeppelin/

Answer (score 4):

**For brownie**

I was able to run slither scan directly on my `.sol` contract file (not on brownie project folder)

- **(Optional)** I had to import dependencies in the project folder (as in my case brownie was installed globally).
- I ran the following command for my contract

```
slither contracts/MyToken.sol --solc-remaps "@openzeppelin=dependencies/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.6.0 @chainlink=dependencies/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.4.1"
```

Here is my directory structure

```
├── brownie-config.yaml
├── contracts
│   ├── MyToken.sol
├── dependencies
│   ├── OpenZeppelin
│   └── smartcontractkit
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a lot of libraries, i found this answer that seems to do the trick:

From root directory

```
slither contracts/WeakToken.sol --solc-remaps @=node_modules/@
```

source: https://github.com/crytic/slither/issues/1121#issuecomment-1083342599

Answer (score 0):

**From Your Root Directory:**

> slither contracts/WeakToken.sol --solc-remaps
> @openzeppelin/=$(pwd)/node_modules/@openzeppelin/

#Special Thanks to @Mauricio Perdomo

Answer (score 0):

If you simply download the zip from OZ github and unpack in same directory, then:

```
slither contract.sol --solc-remaps @openzeppelin=openzeppelin-contracts-master/
```

Answer (score 0):

all the above does not work for me .
use yaml file:

cat foundry.toml

```
[profile.default]
src = "src"
out = "out"
libs = ["lib"]

remappings = ["@openzeppelin/=node_modules/@openzeppelin/"]
```

then

```
slither .
```

works !