# Slither - File not found. Searched the following locations: "". -- OPENZEPPELIN

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, slither

So I tried with all of the [Slither Tool Error On Contract That Inherit From Openzeppeling](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/107416/slither-tool-error-on-contract-that-inherit-from-openzeppeling) solutions, but none of them worked for me.

I got all openzeppelin files downloaded locally with git clone, but it also didn't work.

[image]

[image]

I also tried installing same tool with Docker but also got the same problem.

When I change import to "./Ownable.sol" to search for files locally it finds the files but only the ones that I have in same directory, and then fails on searching for other dependecies. ( I moved all openzeppelin dependecies to the same folder ). I guess only way to work this one out would be to change paths on every dependecy file?

Any other ideas to try?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on where you are located in folder tree when you run `slither`.

Is it a truffle project? Is your build directory standard or changed?

For a truffle project of standard structure, just call this **from root of the project**:

```
slither
```

If you redirected Solidity compiler output to another project, e.g. you have frontend in `client` subfolder and you use Ethereum and Optimism contracts there:

```
slither --truffle-build-directory client/contracts/ethereum-contracts
```

For better help, please describe how exactly you run Slither.

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways:

- ### If you are running **slither from your terminal**:

  - you can simply specify a remapping in a `compiler_config.json` in your main directory:

[image]

---

- ### If you are using the VsCode extension:

  - you can simply specify it in a `remappings.txt` :

[image]

---

**On a different note**:

I also tend to add a `"filter_paths"` in a `slither.config.json`:

[image]

which will allow you to not have included the directories you do not want.